Fast refresh only works when a file only exports components. Use a new file to share constants or functions between components
X.jsx:
import React from 'react';

function X() {
  return (
    <svg width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 28 28" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
      <path d="M14 2C20.6274 2 26 7.37259 26 14C26 20.6274 20.6274 26 14 26C7.37259 26 2 20.6274 2 14C2 7.37259 7.37259 2 14 2Z" fill="black" />
      <path d="M6.60829 7.04756L12.3441 14.7168L6.57214 20.9523H7.87129L12.9248 15.4929L17.0077 20.9523H21.4285L15.3698 12.8517L20.7424 7.04756H19.4432L14.7894 12.0754L11.029 7.04756H6.60829Z" fill="white" />
    </svg>
  );
}

export default X;

I feel everything is correct, but I am getting the error as

Fast refresh only works when a file only exports components. Use a new file to share constants or functions between components.eslint(react-refresh/only-export-components)
function X(): React.JSX.Element

